# How to create a simple function within a class in Python?

Tags: python, function, class

I am starting to work with classes in Python, and am learning how to create functions within classes.  Does anyone have any tips on this sample class & function that I am testing out?

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = None
        self.c = None

    def prod(self): 
        return self.a * self.b

trial = test
trial.a = 4
trial.b = 5
print trial.prod
```

Ideally the result would be to see the number 20.

Comment: You need to use: `trial = test()` and `trial.prod()`

Comment: Classes are objects too. No *instance* is created above - see what `trial` is.

Comment: Good point, done.  That now leaves the result as `<bound method of test.prod of <__main__.test instance at 0x000....>>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to:

1. Create an instance of `test`.
2. Invoke the `prod` method of that instance.

Both of these can be accomplished by adding `()` after their names:

```
trial = test()
trial.a = 4
trial.b = 5
print trial.prod()
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> class test:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.a = None
...         self.b = None
...         self.c = None
...     def prod(self):
...         return self.a * self.b
...
>>> trial = test()
>>> trial.a = 4
>>> trial.b = 5
>>> print trial.prod()
20
>>>
```

---

Without the parenthesis, this line:

```
trial = test
```

is simply assigning the variable `trial` to class `test` itself, not an instance of it.  Moreover, this line:

```
print trial.prod
```

is just printing the string representation of `test.prod`, not the value returned by invoking it.

---

Here is a reference on [Python classes and OOP](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Thanks very much.  First question ever on the site!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you could also pass in the values to a, b, c as parameters to your object's constructor:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def prod(self): 
        return self.a * self.b
```

Then, constructing and calling the function would look like this:

```
 trial = test(4, 5, None)
 print trial.prod()
```